# How to decode Azure B2C cookie

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, adal.js

I have hard time making my Azure B2C renewing procedure work.
So if my cookie is visible when I access the login url (login.microsoftonline.com), under x-ms-cpim-sso:myApp.onmicrosoft.com_0, is there a way to decode its value?

I would like to see when it expires and other related iformation.

Comment: Hi @DavidH, can you please explain what you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: Well I am not able to renew my Azure B2C token after an hour so I would like to debug the cookie on the login.microsoftonline.com. Here is my original issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267456/cannot-renew-access-token-from-b2c-error-aadb2c90077

Comment: After discussion with Microsoft technical support team, the cookie can simply not be decoded.